# Timestamp updating value over every item in a list rather than each one individually

Tags: python, html, django

New to Django here, I have two Django classes representing two different lists:

```
models.py

class Playinglist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    game_id = models.IntegerField()
    started_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Playedlist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    game_id = models.IntegerField()
    finished_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And two functions that add data from one list to another:

```
views.py

def add_to_playinglist(request, game_id):
    obj = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)

    if obj:
        obj.delete()
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        playing_game = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    else:
        obj = Playinglist()
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.game_id = game_id
        obj.save()
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        playing_game = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    
def add_to_playedlist(request, game_id):
    obj = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)

    if obj:
        obj.delete()
        game = Playinglist.objects.get(game_id=game_id)
        played_game = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    else:
        obj = Playedlist()
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.game_id = game_id
        obj.save()
        
        game = Playinglist.objects.get(game_id=game_id)
        game.delete()

        played_game = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
```

And to organize/display that data I am using this function:

```
def profile(request):
    playinglist = Playinglist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playinglist_items = []
    playing = 0
    present_in_playinglist = False
    if playinglist:
        for item in playinglist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playinglist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playinglist = True
                playing += 1
                playinglist = Playinglist.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                
            except:
                present_in_playinglist = False

    playedlist = Playedlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playedlist_items = []
    finished = 0
    present_in_playedlist = False
    if playedlist:
        for item in playedlist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playedlist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playedlist = True
                finished += 1
                playedlist = Playedlist.objects.get(game_id=item.game_id)

            except:
                present_in_playedlist = False

    context = {
        "playinglist": playinglist,
        "playedlist": playedlist,
        "present_in_playlist": present_in_playlist,
        "playlist_items": playlist_items,
        "saved": saved,
        "present_in_playinglist": present_in_playinglist,
        "playinglist_items": playinglist_items,
        "playing": playing,
        "present_in_playedlist": present_in_playedlist,
        "playedlist_items": playedlist_items,
        "finished": finished
    }

    return render(request, "capstone/profile.html", context)
```

Then I am using an html page to display the data:

```
{% if present_in_playinglist %}
   {% for game in playinglist_items %}
      <p>Started on: {{ playinglist.started_on }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   <h6>No games currently playing.</h6>
{% endif %}

{% if present_in_playedlist %}
   {% for game in playedlist_items %}
      <p>Started on: {{ playedlist.finished_on}}</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   <h6>No games played.</h6>
{% endif %}
```

Right now When I append an item to my `playinglist_items` list in my `profile` function I am getting the timestamp for when I added it. However, when I add another item to that list it will add the timestamp it has for that newest item to every other item in the list, so I end up with every item in that respected list having the same timestamp. What can I add or rearrange that allows me to have the timestamps accurately reflect when they were originally added to that list? I can't tell if it's a loop i'm stuck in through my html render or through my `views.py` code. Would be happy to show more code if it may help!

Comment: Hello, could rephrase the last paragraph, it's a bit hard to understand the problem and the different elements you are referring to. "When I add an item to a list" - What item in what list and where in the code?

Comment: @Benjamin_Mourgues Hi, i've edited the last paragraphs to be more specific. Let me know if it still is not clear enough, thanks!